# Issue uploading a custom font to a HTML5 in Google Web Designer

Tags: html, css, google-web-designer

I'm trying to build a HTML5 file in Google Web Designer and need to add a custom font into the file. I'm using @font-face code to import the custom font into the project, but it's not working. This is the code snippet I used:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: "Italian Plate No2-Black";
      src: url("assets/ItalianPlateNo2-Black.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
```

The file I'm trying to import is visible in the project, but is grayed out so I'm unsure if the code is able to use it at the current state.

I have tried using a different file format (.otf), but that didn't work either.

Would appreciate any help here!

Comment: could you also add how you are setting the font on your elements?

Comment: I tried setting it within the code with a snippet like this:"p {
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: ItalianPlateNo2-Black !important;
    }"  , but also just using the interface of the Google Web Designer. Is there a specific part of the code I need to add the font to separately? Sorry if this is a basic question, really out of my depth here!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HTML to use link custom fonts from Google Fonts and select which custom font you want to use and link it to HTML file and then give its Font properties in CSS

for example it should look something like this

```
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@100;200&family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

paste this in head section of HTML file

and in CSS file

```
body{
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;`
}
```

paste this

you should be able to get the font family in google fonts itself